# How can I trace web service response in brackets(Development tool for PHP like notepad ++)?

Tags: php, visual-studio, adobe-brackets

I'm using brackets for my PHP development, I want to **trace web service** response in brackets, that what is coming out from web service, as you can see response in android studio.

is there any plugin for this task ? Or should I move to visual studio? does visual studio show response in terminal ?

Comment: brackets? what do you mean by them?

Comment: brackets is a development tool, like text editor, notepad, sublime etc

Comment: no idea about that man, you may print the value to check it or may be console.log to check value on the console